# Scala : How to break out of a nested for comprehension

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write some code as below -

```
def kthSmallest(matrix: Array[Array[Int]], k: Int): Int = {
  val pq = new PriorityQueue[Int]() //natural ordering
  var count = 0

  for (
    i <- matrix.indices;
    j <- matrix(0).indices
  ) yield {
      pq += matrix(i)(j)
      count += 1
  } //This would yield Any!

  pq.dequeue() //kth smallest. 

}
```

My question is, that I only want to loop till the time count is less than k (something like takeWhile(count != k)), but as I'm also inserting elements into the priority queue in the yield, this won't work in the current state.

My other options are to write a nested loop and return once count reaches k. Is it possible to do with yield? I could not find a idiomatic way of doing it yet. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: you're mixing imperative and functional. You either do this fully functional (removing the queue) or you do it fully imperative (using a regular for loop, therefore removing the yield)

Comment: The PriorityQueue is a implementation from scala.collection.mutable. How else to add to a mutable collection?

Comment: @Chobeat why? It's perfectly doable mixing concepts from both paradigms.

Comment: @learningTheRopes you're mixing 2 things: Building the queue is one thing. Dequeuing is another. Ever though of having 2 separate methods or functions?

Comment: @pedromss for sure it's possible but in this case is not advisable. It makes things more complicated

Comment: Your assumption that you need to stop after accumulating k elements is incorrect. That way, you are finding not the "kth smallest", but rather "the smallest of the first k", which makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not idiomatic for Scala to use `var`s or break loops. You can go for recursion, lazy evaluation or duct tape a `break`, giving up on some performance (just like `return`, it's implemented as an Exception, and won't perform well enough). Here are the options broken down:

1. Use recursion - recursive algorithms are the analog of loops in functional languages

   ```
   def kthSmallest(matrix: Array[Array[Int]], k: Int): Int = {
     val pq = new PriorityQueue[Int]() //natural ordering

     @tailrec
     def fillQueue(i: Int, j: Int, count: Int): Unit =
       if (count >= k || i >= matrix.length) ()
       else {
         pq += matrix(i)(j)
         fillQueue(
           if (j >= matrix(i).length - 1) i + 1 else i,
           if (j >= matrix(i).length - 1) 0 else j + 1,
           count + 1)
       }

     fillQueue(0, 0, 0)

     pq.dequeue() //kth smallest.
   }
   ```
2. Use a lazy structure, as chengpohi suggested - this doesn't sound very much like a pure function though. I'd suggest to use an `Iterator` instead of a `Stream` in this case though - as iterators don't memoize the steps they've gone through (might spare some memory for large matrices).
3. For those desperately willing to use `break`, Scala supports it in an attachable fashion (note the performance caveat mentioned above):

   ```
   import scala.util.control.Breaks

   breakable {
     // loop code
     break
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I had a feeling "recurse instead!" would be the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way using the `Stream` **lazy evaluation** to do this. Since `for yield` is equal to `flatMap`, you can convert `for yield` to `flatMap` with `Stream`:

```
matrix.indices.toStream.flatMap(i => {
  matrix(0).indices.toStream.map(j => {
    pq += matrix(i)(j)
    count += 1
  })
}).takeWhile(_ => count <= k)
```

Use `toStream` to convert the **collection** to `Stream`, and Since `Stream` is **lazy evaluation**, so we can use `takeWhile` to **predicate count** to terminate the less loops without init others.

Comment: I don't think making it a `Stream` buys you anything. After all the matrix is already sitting around in memory. Converting it into a series of nested `Stream`s first doesn't change that

Comment: `Stream` is lazy right? the count is lazy to calculate too.

Comment: Ah never mind, I was reading too quickly and I was wrong; I see what you're doing here. In which case I'd agree with @Sergey. Having each element of the stream evaluated for its side effects and immediately thrown away without ever inspecting its elements feels non-idiomatic.